# PHPUnit Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, phpunit

I tried running PHPUnit this morning and it's producing a Segmentation Fault 11 error (using the command `phpunit unit/` - If I run PHPUnit on my functional tests with Selenium then everything works fine, it's only the unit tests that are affected, I've tried the options in other threads here and those didn't fix the issue, and I have tried reinstalling MAMP locally and reinstalling PHPUnit through PEAR. I've also tried switching PHP versions on the command-line.

The tests run fine on a colleagues laptop, and they run fine within Jenkins. Does anyone have any ideas as to the issue? I've included the output from the console.

```
Process:         php [2337]
Path:            /Applications/MAMP/*/php
Identifier:      php
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [586]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2012-11-07 11:09:51.924 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   php                             0x0000000100653e75 zend_hash_get_current_key_type_ex + 69
1   php                             0x000000010044d783 zif_spl_autoload_call + 611
2   php                             0x0000000100626111 zend_call_function + 5617
3   php                             0x0000000100626b83 zend_lookup_class_ex + 1267
4   php                             0x0000000100628116 zend_fetch_class_by_name + 86
5   php                             0x000000010068bfb5 ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER + 261
6   php                             0x00000001006866cc execute + 1788
7   php                             0x000000010063cba3 zend_execute_scripts + 707
8   php                             0x0000000100593e40 php_execute_script + 1232
9   php                             0x00000001007e0c1a do_cli + 3642
10  php                             0x00000001007e2765 main + 3461
11  php                             0x0000000100001064 start + 52

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x737469762f656f73  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbfdb20  rdx: 0xffffffffffffff13
  rdi: 0x0000000101a378c8  rsi: 0x00007fff5fbfdb20  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfda90  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfda90
   r8: 0x00007fff5fbfd338   r9: 0x0000000000000002  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000102dd2138
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x0000000100653e75  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x0000000101ba6e00
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100ec7fe7 +php (???) <61B89CD8-FA9E-3D2B-BDCE-35DFCA7CC017> /Applications/MAMP/*/php
       0x10112d000 -        0x101143fff +libexslt.0.dylib (9.15) <10AA2D0E-42B0-30DC-BC01-6C10BD757061> /Applications/MAMP/*/libexslt.0.dylib
       0x10114a000 -        0x101255fe7 +libiconv.2.dylib (8.1) <19C34294-DBD8-3DA6-8663-35549D3A80BF> /Applications/MAMP/*/libiconv.2.dylib
       0x101263000 -        0x1012c7fff +libt1.5.dylib (7.2) <BB17E324-EA0E-3716-88F8-4EDF9AC61B21> /Applications/MAMP/*/libt1.5.dylib
       0x1012ea000 -        0x1013b6fef +libfreetype.6.dylib (15) <C6D12969-73A9-3C8D-ADCF-D2CDC72167AD> /Applications/MAMP/*/libfreetype.6.dylib
       0x1013cf000 -        0x10140cfef +libpng15.15.dylib (23) <D5E80405-5E4B-38A9-B668-9E7112122A3E> /Applications/MAMP/*/libpng15.15.dylib
       0x101414000 -        0x10146dfef +libjpeg.8.dylib (13) <253D68BC-090B-3FC1-BE0E-FB663612C639> /Applications/MAMP/*/libjpeg.8.dylib
       0x101475000 -        0x1014c1ff7 +libcurl.4.dylib (7) <42B08966-8867-305A-9FEB-7D969D69A0C7> /Applications/MAMP/*/libcurl.4.dylib
       0x1014cf000 -        0x10169cfff +libxml2.2.dylib (10.8) <3A40C660-9099-309E-A108-4B68471D1579> /Applications/MAMP/*/libxml2.2.dylib
       0x1016d3000 -        0x101706fef +libidn.11.dylib (18) <73EAB24B-0A33-39C4-8FA5-FDAE0C99DC1E> /Applications/MAMP/*/libidn.11.dylib
       0x10170c000 -        0x101759ff7 +libxslt.1.dylib (3.26) <F85DB243-D7D4-3C21-B94C-118754A6D9DD> /Applications/MAMP/*/libxslt.1.dylib
       0x101765000 -        0x101775fe7 +libintl.8.dylib (10.1) <1024FD8E-208D-3620-8044-153D50FFE252> /Applications/MAMP/*/libintl.8.dylib
       0x1017dd000 -        0x1017e9fff +yaz.so (???) <CCE413E9-517D-3273-8F1C-4F4555227B2B> /Applications/MAMP/*/yaz.so
       0x1017ee000 -        0x1017f8ff7 +mcrypt.so (???) <AA475210-CD61-390F-B70D-45AD57D81E18> /Applications/MAMP/*/mcrypt.so
       0x101b8f000 -        0x101bb7fff +xcache.so (???) <2BE6192A-B4F9-3BB5-9354-E63AC94C8A90> /Applications/MAMP/*/xcache.so
       0x101bc4000 -        0x101cbbff7 +imap.so (???) <1F9C357E-C2E6-3696-BA29-B4289B570053> /Applications/MAMP/*/imap.so
       0x101cf1000 -        0x101dbdfe7 +libyaz.4.dylib (5) <442CDE8C-28B0-38BF-BD96-50D5C3FD4891> /Applications/MAMP/*/libyaz.4.dylib
       0x101ea6000 -        0x101ee5ff7 +libmcrypt.4.dylib (9.8) <AFF632C5-CB59-34B1-A1EE-930D3A7360C0> /Applications/MAMP/*/libmcrypt.4.dylib
       0x101ef8000 -        0x101f03fef +libltdl.7.dylib (11) <06131575-5BE7-34DD-A39B-6384B31EF9B6> /Applications/MAMP/*/libltdl.7.dylib
       0x101f08000 -        0x101f09ff7 +gettext.so (???) <49C7C695-9117-3405-919A-5AC4CEC8201E> /Applications/MAMP/*/gettext.so
       0x101f0c000 -        0x101f31fff +pgsql.so (???) <9B7AC465-52F3-321F-BAB0-7DDEC76F89B7> /Applications/MAMP/*/pgsql.so
       0x101f3c000 -        0x101f68ff7 +libpq.5.dylib (5.2) <1CDE4910-D92A-33B8-A891-C66A41F2E8C0> /Applications/MAMP/*/libpq.5.dylib
       0x101f72000 -        0x101f7bff7 +pdo_pgsql.so (???) <441676E4-EA9A-35D3-ABFA-C00AF11D0489> /Applications/MAMP/*/pdo_pgsql.so
       0x101f80000 -        0x101f81fff  com.apple.heimdalodpac (10.8 - 198) <AE9D93D6-C970-368B-A89C-2DA0EB225204>     /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/heimdalodpac.bundle/Contents/MacOS/heimdalodpac
       0x101f86000 -        0x101f88fff  com.apple.KerberosHelper.LKDCLocate (4.0 - 1.0) <6276FDFA-EB44-374C-9BFC-2AB5F68F2145>     /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/LKDCLocate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/LKDCLocate
       0x101f8c000 -        0x101f8dff7  com.apple.kerberos.reachability (3.0 - 2.0) <8DC5EA50-F572-31C7-9443-5F6C9363A58D>     /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/Reachability.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Reachability
       0x101f91000 -        0x101f92ff7  com.apple.kerberos.sckerberosconfig (3.0 - 1) <6981ADC2-C901-3F8A-A3D0-7334DE61BF3E>     /System/Library/KerberosPlugins/KerberosFrameworkPlugins/SCKerberosConfig.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SCKerberosConfig
       0x102800000 -        0x102a42ff7 +pdo_mysql.so (???) <941A3356-75E9-303B-A1BF-774B9458CB63> /Applications/MAMP/*/pdo_mysql.so
    0x7fff68009000 -     0x7fff6803d93f  dyld (210.2.3) <A40597AA-5529-3337-8C09-D8A014EB1578> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8dffd000 -     0x7fff8e01fff7  com.apple.Kerberos (2.0 - 1) <C49B8820-34ED-39D7-A407-A3E854153556> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff8e020000 -     0x7fff8e021ff7  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.18) <E7595861-ECF9-336E-9901-BED2620FAA80> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x7fff8e0b7000 -     0x7fff8e413fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.8 - 945.11) <A5D41956-A354-3ACC-9355-BE200072223B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.    framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff8e819000 -     0x7fff8eae9fff  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55179.1) <639641EF-8156-3190-890C-1053658E044A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff8eb02000 -     0x7fff8eb0afff  liblaunch.dylib (442.26.2) <2F71CAF8-6524-329E-AC56-C506658B4C0C> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8eb12000 -     0x7fff8eb9fff7  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <C7F43889-F8BF-3CB9-AD66-11AEFCBCEDE7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.    framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff8eccd000 -     0x7fff8edcafff  libsqlite3.dylib (138.1) <ADE9CB98-D77D-300C-A32A-556B7440769F> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff8edcb000 -     0x7fff8ede0ff7  libdispatch.dylib (228.23) <D26996BF-FC57-39EB-8829-F63585561E09> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8ede1000 -     0x7fff8ede6fff  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.8 - 151.10) <CF44120B-9B01-32DD-852E-C9C0E1243FC0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.    framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff8f5c8000 -     0x7fff8f8dfff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1037.3 - 1037.3) <DF7CABCA-F2CB-345B-8EFF-F0F4E937B7FF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.    framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff8feb1000 -     0x7fff8fed0ff7  libresolv.9.dylib (51) <0882DC2D-A892-31FF-AD8C-0BB518C48B23> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff9021c000 -     0x7fff90405fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.8 - 744.12) <EF002794-DAEF-31C6-866C-E3E3AC387A9F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.    framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff90606000 -     0x7fff90641fff  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5) <0190B746-F684-3F43-B4D0-148EFE386CA4> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
    0x7fff90642000 -     0x7fff907b6fff  com.apple.CFNetwork (596.2.3 - 596.2.3) <6A16C2BD-1035-30F9-AE96-D9E3BB54A976> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.    framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff907b7000 -     0x7fff907d9ff7  libxpc.dylib (140.41) <FAC04D8B-680E-325F-8F0C-DD69859D0E01> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff9116b000 -     0x7fff9116bfff  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (148.2) <B8061D13-C1B2-38D5-A723-9A98D64E67AC> /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
    0x7fff91295000 -     0x7fff9129afff  libcache.dylib (57) <65187C6E-3FBF-3EB8-A1AA-389445E2984D> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff91426000 -     0x7fff914a7fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 707.3) <A45D75C1-B311-39F0-AF4A-63FCCC098C1D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.    framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff91510000 -     0x7fff91547ff7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (47) <923945E6-C489-3406-903B-A362410753F8> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff919f5000 -     0x7fff91a0cfff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.8 - 151.10) <FFBBA538-00B5-334E-BA5B-C8AD6CDCDA14> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.    framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff91bbb000 -     0x7fff91bc0fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30) <08F8731D-5961-39F1-AD00-4590321D24A9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff91dc4000 -     0x7fff91dd7ff7  libbsm.0.dylib (32) <F497D3CE-40D9-3551-84B4-3D5E39600737> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff91dd8000 -     0x7fff91dd9ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (169.3) <365477AB-D641-389D-B8F4-A1FAE9657EEE> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff91e09000 -     0x7fff91e0afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (59) <D92DCBC3-541C-37BD-AADE-ACC75A0C59C8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff9208a000 -     0x7fff9208afff  libkeymgr.dylib (25) <CC9E3394-BE16-397F-926B-E579B60EE429> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff92c04000 -     0x7fff92c04fff  com.apple.CoreServices (57 - 57) <9DD44CB0-C644-35C3-8F57-0B41B3EC147D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.    framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff92c08000 -     0x7fff92d0afff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (47) <74F165AD-4572-3B26-B0E2-A97477FE59D0> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff92d0b000 -     0x7fff92d2cff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (33) <736ABE58-8DED-3289-A042-C25AF7AE5B23> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff92d64000 -     0x7fff92e7c92f  libobjc.A.dylib (532.2) <90D31928-F48D-3E37-874F-220A51FD9E37> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff92ee1000 -     0x7fff92f92fff  com.apple.LaunchServices (539.7 - 539.7) <DA7C602E-5E01-31B8-925D-B45360CA089F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.    framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff93062000 -     0x7fff9312efe7  libsystem_c.dylib (825.25) <8CBCF9B9-EBB7-365E-A3FF-2F3850763C6B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff9312f000 -     0x7fff9313cfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib (29) <CE9785E8-B535-3504-B392-82F0064D9AF2> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff93289000 -     0x7fff9328aff7  libremovefile.dylib (23.1) <DBBFAF35-AC78-3856-92F6-6E4FD9DF14A2> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff9340c000 -     0x7fff9345bff7  libcorecrypto.dylib (106.2) <CE0C29A3-C420-339B-ADAA-52F4683233CC> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff93f5b000 -     0x7fff93f61fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.5.1 - 2.5.1) <F7DAF7CC-5893-3F06-9168-3B0192B66D15> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.    framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff93f63000 -     0x7fff93f94ff7  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 184.4) <054F2D6F-9CFF-3EF1-9778-25C551B616C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.    framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff94015000 -     0x7fff94066ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.12.2 - 1.12.2) <E095637C-457F-3D8F-AE32-A032F9D5A46C> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.    framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff94067000 -     0x7fff94164ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (22.3) <47B09CB2-C636-3024-8B55-6040F7829B4C> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff94621000 -     0x7fff94623ff7  libunc.dylib (25) <92805328-CD36-34FF-9436-571AB0485072> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff946f7000 -     0x7fff948f7fff  libicucore.A.dylib (491.11.1) <CC318A27-878A-38CE-9292-1B98353FA9C7> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff948f8000 -     0x7fff94903fff  libsystem_notify.dylib (98.5) <C49275CC-835A-3207-AFBA-8C01374927B6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff94998000 -     0x7fff94a3eff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (557.4 - 557.4) <841878A8-6F3E-300D-8F01-444B3CC1F41D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.    framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff94d70000 -     0x7fff94dddff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0 - 755.18.10) <142E19DD-1C8D-3D61-ABC8-83994A73279F> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff94e7a000 -     0x7fff94e88ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (77.10) <0D99F24E-56FE-380F-B81B-4A4C630EE587> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff94e89000 -     0x7fff94e8bfff  libquarantine.dylib (52) <4BE2E642-A14F-340A-B482-5BD2AEFD9C24> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff95049000 -     0x7fff95077ff7  libsystem_m.dylib (3022.6) <B434BE5C-25AB-3EBD-BAA7-5304B34E3441> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff955cc000 -     0x7fff95639fff  com.apple.datadetectorscore (4.0 - 269.1) <C94C372B-3821-3A46-A8C2-091AB1CFF7F4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.    framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
    0x7fff9563a000 -     0x7fff9563dff7  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <F59367C9-C110-382B-A695-9035A6DD387E> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff956f8000 -     0x7fff956fcfff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <C8F45864-5B58-3237-87E1-2C258A1D73B8> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff9590a000 -     0x7fff95911fff  libcopyfile.dylib (89) <876573D0-E907-3566-A108-577EAD1B6182> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff95b16000 -     0x7fff95b28ff7  libz.1.dylib (43) <2A1551E8-A272-3DE5-B692-955974FE1416> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff95b4b000 -     0x7fff95b76fff  libxslt.1.dylib (11.3) <441776B8-9130-3893-956F-39C85FFA644F> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff95b77000 -     0x7fff95badfff  libsystem_info.dylib (406.17) <4FFCA242-7F04-365F-87A6-D4EFB89503C1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff95bb3000 -     0x7fff95bbbff7  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (379.32.1) <62AA0B84-188A-348B-8F9E-3E2DB08DB93C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff95cda000 -     0x7fff95cffff7  libc++abi.dylib (24.4) <E7BD9363-1D25-3551-A68A-2E2FF6ABECD7> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff95d00000 -     0x7fff95d69fff  libstdc++.6.dylib (56) <EAA2B53E-EADE-39CF-A0EF-FB9D4940672A> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff96e72000 -     0x7fff96e74fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 23) <A97D348B-32BF-3E52-8DF2-59BFAD21E1A3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.    framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff96e75000 -     0x7fff96e86ff7  libsasl2.2.dylib (166) <649CAE0E-8FFE-3C60-A849-BE6300E4B726> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff96efc000 -     0x7fff96f7efff  com.apple.Heimdal (3.0 - 2.0) <660A6C64-4912-32C8-A332-B64164032A2D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
    0x7fff972dd000 -     0x7fff972ebfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60026) <2D6537F5-1B5E-305C-A1CF-D1FA80CA3939> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff97730000 -     0x7fff97798ff7  libc++.1.dylib (65.1) <20E31B90-19B9-3C2A-A9EB-474E08F9FE05> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff98016000 -     0x7fff9810bfff  libiconv.2.dylib (34) <FEE8B996-EB44-37FA-B96E-D379664DEFE1> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff99a4b000 -     0x7fff99a62fff  com.apple.GenerationalStorage (1.1 - 132.2) <3F5C87BD-D866-3732-8CB9-D23ED9784D6E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.    framework/Versions/A/GenerationalStorage
    0x7fff99d95000 -     0x7fff99d99ff7  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <F2F3B753-FC73-3543-8BBE-859FDBB4D6A6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
    0x7fff99d9a000 -     0x7fff99da1fff  com.apple.NetFS (5.0 - 4.0) <82E24B9A-7742-3DA3-9E99-ED267D98C05E> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff99da2000 -     0x7fff99dafff7  com.apple.NetAuth (4.0 - 4.0) <F5BC7D7D-AF28-3C83-A674-DADA48FF7810> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff99db4000 -     0x7fff99dcfff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.18.24) <C0535565-35D1-31A7-A744-63D9F10F12A4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff99e52000 -     0x7fff99e53ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (220) <3C3B03CF-C525-3CB3-8557-62E91B93AC95> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff99e99000 -     0x7fff99e9ffff  libmacho.dylib (829) <BF332AD9-E89F-387E-92A4-6E1AB74BD4D9> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff9a0fb000 -     0x7fff9a147ff7  libauto.dylib (185.1) <73CDC482-16E3-3FC7-9BB4-FBA2DA44DBC2> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff9a220000 -     0x7fff9a22eff7  libkxld.dylib (2050.18.24) <7027CE49-007D-3553-8FFA-3E3B428B2316> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff9a241000 -     0x7fff9a242fff  liblangid.dylib (116) <864C409D-D56B-383E-9B44-A435A47F2346> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff9a243000 -     0x7fff9a249ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.1) <21703D36-2DAB-3D8B-8442-EAAB23C060D3> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff9a7aa000 -     0x7fff9a7b9ff7  libxar.1.dylib (105) <370ED355-E516-311E-BAFD-D80633A84BE1> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff9a867000 -     0x7fff9a8a1fff  com.apple.GSS (3.0 - 2.0) <0BDF8090-5EF4-3759-94DE-8521D74188AA> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fff9a94d000 -     0x7fff9a9aaff7  com.apple.AE (645.3 - 645.3) <FF867ACA-8628-3E5A-8FA0-AF429B42C5D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.    framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff9aa0f000 -     0x7fff9aa10fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (8) <8548E0DC-0D2F-30B6-B045-FE8A038E76D8> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff9aa11000 -     0x7fff9aa1cfff  com.apple.CommonAuth (3.0 - 2.0) <74A86DDD-57D0-3178-AB74-E1F31DBFFC39> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.    framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1596
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=111.2M resident=43.1M(39%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=68.1M(61%)
Writable regions: Total=27.0M written=6936K(25%) resident=9208K(33%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=18.0M(67%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
MALLOC                             17.7M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           4K
__DATA                             6248K
__LINKEDIT                         55.5M
__TEXT                             55.6M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             199.5M
```

I'm using PHP 5.4.4 (but have tried with 5.3.14 and 5.2.17), the PHPUnit version is 3.7.9.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this earlier this morning. The problem was that Yii was attempting to unregister an autoload function that didn't exist, it was likely removed in a later version of PHPUnit as I was a few minor versions ahead of my colleague. PHP throws a SIGSEGV when attempting to unregister a non-existant autoloader.

So I have changed these lines in Yii: framework/test/CTestCase.php

```
spl_autoload_unregister('phpunit_autoload');
Yii::registerAutoloader('phpunit_autoload');
```

to:

```
if (in_array('phpunit_autoload', spl_autoload_functions())) {
    spl_autoload_unregister('phpunit_autoload');
    Yii::registerAutoloader('phpunit_autoload');
}
```

This has fixed the issue. This change has already been implemented in Yii on the Git repository, but not released publicly yet. A bug report already exists on bugs.php.net too. I've answered this so it may help anyone else who has the same issue.

Comment: +1 for reporting it to bugs.php.net; Hurray for crash reports :)